# Query string parameter in swagger documentation not sent as array in request

Tags: rest, symfony, swagger, api-platform.com

I am currently working on project using **Symfony 4.3.4** and **API platform  v2.3.6**.

I am facing 1 issue right now. Let’s say I send a GET request to an enpoint with a query string parameter called **products** because I send **1 or more** product IDs.

I want to get the value of the products parameter in my controller as a **PHP array**.

So my request is

`GET /my/endpoint?products[]=8f391c60-5467-4bf0-917f-e2151337fa7e&products[]=ddaa94e1-af79-4abf-9dfc-a28dd8077f45`

In the controller I perform a dump:

`dump($request->query->get("products"));`

Then I get:

```
array:2 [
  0 => "8f391c60-5467-4bf0-917f-e2151337fa7e"
  1 => "ddaa94e1-af79-4abf-9dfc-a28dd8077f45"
]
```

As you can see the way I pass my product IDs like an array in the query string, I can retrieve the products parameter as a **PHP array**.
My concern here, is the swagger documentation. 
Using this configuration in YAML:

```
collectionOperations:
    operation_name:
        method: get
        path: /my/endpoint
        controller: App\Controller\MyEndpointController
        swagger_context:
            summary: My summary
            description:
                My endpoint description
            responses:
                parameters:
                    -
                        in: query
                        name: products
                        description: "The products IDs parameter"
                        schema:
                            type: array
                            items:
                                type: "string"
                                example: "019fcd9b-beea-4791-8a59-d4e2d02427d6"
```

In the API documentation page when I choose **Try it out** I have to fill in all the parameters value included **products**. The problem is that products parameter appears as a **text input**.

If I remove the **schema** key in the yaml configuration of the parameter and I put `type: array` and `items` keys directly at the same level as `in`, `name` and `description`:

```
parameters:
    -
        in: query
        name: products
        description: "The products IDs parameter"
        type: array
        items:
            type: "string"
            example: "019fcd9b-beea-4791-8a59-d4e2d02427d6"
```

Then the products parameter appears with a button Add item. Each time I click on this button, I can fill a product ID to pass and that is fine. The problem is that when I click on Execute (still in the API documentation page) I have an error because API platform does not send the request with products parameter as a true array but as a string containing all product IDs separated by `,`:

`GET /my/endpoint?products=8f391c60-5467-4bf0-917f-e2151337fa7e,ddaa94e1-af79-4abf-9dfc-a28dd8077f45`

and this is what I want:

`GET /my/endpoint?products[]=8f391c60-5467-4bf0-917f-e2151337fa7e&products[]=ddaa94e1-af79-4abf-9dfc-a28dd8077f45`

any idea about the way to achieve this with API platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query parameter needs to be named `products[]` (with square brackets) and have the [`collectionFormat`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#user-content-parametercollectionformat)`: multi` attribute:

```yaml
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: products[]
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
      format: uuid
    collectionFormat: multi
    # (Optional) Array example to display in Swagger UI
    x-example:
      - 8f391c60-5467-4bf0-917f-e2151337fa7e
      - ddaa94e1-af79-4abf-9dfc-a28dd8077f45
```

Note that query parameters in OpenAPI 2.0 [do not support](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#items-object) the `example` keyword, but some tools (such as Swagger UI) support the `x-example` extension to specify the example values for query parameters.